# For the same set of values, how do I pull just one value from a different column in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, lookup

For each set of PPIDs that has a “Delete” value and no “Reassign”, how would I populate the Intended Result column. In this example, I only need to populate “Delete” for PPIDS 123 and 789 because there is no “Reassign” value
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In cell `C2` try:

```
=IF($B2="Delete",IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$8=$A2)*($B$2:$B$8="Reassign"))=0,"Delete",""),"")
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you may try using the below formula as well in cell `C2`

```
=IF(AND($B2="Delete",COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,A2,$B$2:$B$8,"Reassign")=0),"Delete","")
```

[image: FORMULA]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming to start at A1 for PPID:
B1 cell should contain: if(and(a1=a2,b2=""),"Delete", "")
Copy that formula into all B cells.  The formulas will adjust the references.